# Extending WebSphere SAML Identity propogation

Tags: security, websphere, saml

I have an existing financial application which uses an API gateway to authenticate web-based users. This gateway maintains a security session for the user, and proxies SOAP calls on to a WebSphere box. It adds a signed SAML assertion to these SOAP calls.

A series of JAX-WS Services are deployed on WebSphere, and these are protected with WebSphere policies to consume the SAML assertions. The identity and group memberships specified in the SAML assertions are then propagated to the WebSphere security context for the service call. All works very well, all of the security logic is done purely by configuration.

New requirements now require that we propagate the sessionId in the API gateway all the way through to WebSphere , and beyond. This is for reasons of traceability.

Clearly we could change the WSDL for all of the services to include some Meta-data fields, but this is a big change, and would require very extensive testing.

I was hoping there might be a way to map some arbitrary attributes from the SAML assertion (Other than Identity and groupMembership) to the WebSphere security context. Or even to access the SAML XML in the (authenticated) JAX-WS Service.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have API gateway to add sessionid as an SAML attribute, then retrieve the attribute from Subject after SAML is processed by WebSphere. Here is sample code to get SAML attribute in WebSphere after SAML is processed.

```
    Subject subject = WSSubject.getRunAsSubject();


    SAMLToken samlToken = (SAMLToken) AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction() {
                    public Object run() throws java.lang.Exception
                    {
                        final java.util.Iterator authIterator = subject.getPrivateCredentials(SAMLToken.class).iterator();
                        if ( authIterator.hasNext() ) {
                            final SAMLToken token = (SAMLToken) authIterator.next();
                            return token;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });

    Map<String, String> attributes = samlToken.getStringAttributes();
    List<SAMLAttribute>  attributes = samlToken.getSAMLAttributes();
```

Comment: I have searched for this for so very long - I can't find any trace in any document that SAML Attributes end up in getPrivateCredentials :-( I was so very happy to read you post (And of course to recognise your name.) I will try this onsite first thing tomorrow. Cheers !

Comment: We are using SCA Components under WebSphere Application server 8.5, exposed as JAX-WS service providers. Should the above code still work? We see a saml:attribute coming over the wire in the WS-Security header, but aren't getting anything in the getSAMLAttributes()

Comment: You were able to pull a non-null SAMLToken object off of the Subject?  If you did, and you could see attributed in the inbound SAML token in the Security header, getSAMLAttributes should work.  If you are unable to get the SAML token object off of the header, you need to make sure that you have a caller configuration for the saml token in your provider bindings.  See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/uwbs_wsspsbcald.html

Comment: @Barbara Jenson All good now, works like a charm. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through the creds yourself, you can use the WSSUtilFactory API to do it for you: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/wssecurity/wssapi/WSSUtilFactory.html

Assuming that you are using a SAML 2.0 token, you can do:

```
WSSUtilFactory wssuf = WSSUtilFactory.getInstance();
SAMLToken token = wssuf.getSaml20Token();
```

The getSaml20Token method was added to WSSUtilFactory in 70043, 80013, 85510 and 9000.